# jquery select li value in keydown/up

Tags: jquery, input, html-lists

```
<input type="text" id="region" class="inputs" name="remo">

<ul id="ulList">
<li id="idr0"></li>
<li id="idr1">Baltimore</li>
<li id="idr2">India</li>
<li id="idr3">International - Russia</li>
<li id="idr4">MD 19940</li>
<li id="idr5">Minnesota</li>
<li id="idr6">North Carolina</li>
</ul>
```

i need jquery code for when select keydown/up then set the input value with li value

Comment: We all need some code. What is your question? Is there something you tried to solve the problem that didn't work and you would like to ask about? Because if there isn't this question shouldn't have been asked here. Here's a nice [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) you might read.

Comment: neeed jquery keydown/up function and select the li value

Comment: Add mor information. Which key you want to press? Whats about your li values? Should they cycle? Or what?

Comment: u can give me some example.. so that i can understand what u needed...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#region').live('keypress', function (e) {
                var objCurrentLi, obj = $('#ulList').find('.SelectedLi'), objUl = $('#ulList'), code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

                if (code === 40) {  //Up Arrow
                    if ((obj.length === 0) || (objUl.find('li:last').hasClass('SelectedLi') === true)) {
                        objCurrentLi = objUl.find('li:first').addClass('SelectedLi');
                    }
                    else {
                        objCurrentLi = obj.next().addClass('SelectedLi');
                    }
                    obj.removeClass('SelectedLi');
                }
                else if (code === 38) {  //Down Arrow
                    if ((obj.length === 0) || (objUl.find('li:first').hasClass('SelectedLi') === true)) {
                        objCurrentLi = objUl.find('li:last').addClass('SelectedLi');
                    }
                    else {
                        objCurrentLi = obj.prev().addClass('SelectedLi');
                    }
                    obj.removeClass('SelectedLi');
                }

                $(this).val(objCurrentLi.text());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="region" class="inputs" name="remo" />
    <ul id="ulList">
        <li id="idr0"></li>
        <li id="idr1">Baltimore</li>
        <li id="idr2">India</li>
        <li id="idr3">International - Russia</li>
        <li id="idr4">MD 19940</li>
        <li id="idr5">Minnesota</li>
        <li id="idr6">North Carolina</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```